# I am trying to figure out how to show only some dates when select some grade

Tags: javascript, html, forms, conditional-statements

when any one select 5 to 9 grades it has to hide only some dates like 18 dec to 25 dec and when select class x it has to show all the dates

here i am attaching the code class studying is where user can choose the grade and online exam dates is where to show conditional dates

```
<!--Dropdown-->
        <label>Class currently studying in
        <em>*</em>
        </label>
        <select id="csin" name="Dropdown4"><option selected="true" value="-Select-">-Select-</option>
        <option id="cthoc" value="Class V">Class V</option>
        <option id="cthoc" value="Class VI">Class VI</option>
        <option id="cthoc" value="Class VII">Class VII</option>
        <option id="cthoc" value="Class VIII">Class VIII</option>
        <option id="cthoc" value="Class IX">Class IX</option>
        <option value="Class&#x20;X">Class X</option>
        </select>
    
        </div>
    </section>

    
    
    <section class="ep ep4 epm">

        

        <div class="column">
            <label>Mode of Exam
                <em>*</em>
                </label>
               <select id="QuestionOptions" name="Dropdown1">
               
                <option select value="Online">Online</option>
                <option id="option_2" value="Offline">Offline</option>
                </select>
        </div>

        <div id="A" class="column">
            <label>Online Exam Dates
                <em>*</em>
                </label>
                <select id="od" name="Dropdown2"><option selected="true" value="-Select-">-Select-</option>
                    <option id="ctho" value="Dec&#x20;18,&#x20;2021">Dec 18, 2021</option>
                    <option id="ctho" value="Dec&#x20;19,&#x20;2021">Dec 19, 2021</option>
                    <option id="ctho" value="Dec&#x20;20,&#x20;2021">Dec 20, 2021</option>
                    <option id="ctho" value="Dec&#x20;21,&#x20;2021">Dec 21, 2021</option>
                    <option id="ctho" value="Dec&#x20;22,&#x20;2021">Dec 22, 2021</option>
                    <option id="ctho" value="Dec&#x20;23,&#x20;2021">Dec 23, 2021</option>
                    <option id="ctho" value="Dec&#x20;24,&#x20;2021">Dec 24, 2021</option>
                    <option id="ctho" value="Dec&#x20;25,&#x20;2021">Dec 25, 2021</option>
                    <option id="ctho2" value="Dec&#x20;26,&#x20;2021">Dec 26, 2021</option>
                    <option id="ctho2" value="Dec&#x20;27,&#x20;2021">Dec 27, 2021</option>
                    <option id="ctho2" value="Dec&#x20;28,&#x20;2021">Dec 28, 2021</option>
                    <option id="ctho2" value="Dec&#x20;29,&#x20;2021">Dec 29, 2021</option>
                    <option id="ctho2" value="Dec&#x20;30,&#x20;2021">Dec 30, 2021</option>
                    <option id="ctho2" value="Dec&#x20;31,&#x20;2021">Dec 31, 2021</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        
    

            <div id="B" class="column">
            <label>Offline Exam Dates
                <em>*</em>
                </label>
                <select name="Dropdown3"><option selected="true" value="-Select-">-Select-</option>
                <option value="Dec&#x20;18,&#x20;2021">Dec 18, 2021</option>
                
                </select>
            </div>
```

i tried so many javascript codes

```
<script>
    $("#A,#B").hide();
   $("#csin").change(function(){
    
        if($(this).val() == "Class V")
        if($(this).val() == "Class VI")
        if($(this).val() == "Class VII")
        if($(this).val() == "Class VIII")
        if($(this).val() == "Class IX"){
        $("#C").show();
        $("#A").hide();
        $("#B").hide();
        }else{
        $("#C").hide(); 
      }
      
    });
```

but it's not working

how can I achieve my goal

Answer (score 0):

Put the condition like

```
 if ($(this).val() == "Class V" || $(this).val() == "Class VI" || $(this).val() == "Class VII" || $(this).val() == "Class VIII" || $(this).val() == "Class IX")
```

and if true then  I hide the date less then 26 using below code

```
 $("#od").children('option').each(function () {
                if (this.value != "-Select-" && this.value.replace(/^\D+/g, '').split(",")[0] < 26) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
```

here is a working demo hope this is what you want to achieve if not please correct me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#csin").change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "Class V" || $(this).val() == "Class VI" || $(this).val() == "Class VII" || $(this).val() == "Class VIII" || $(this).val() == "Class IX") {
                    $("#od").children('option').each(function () {
                        if (this.value != "-Select-" && this.value.replace(/^\D+/g, '').split(",")[0] < 26) {
                            $(this).hide();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#od").children('option').each(function () {
                        if (this.value.replace(/^\D+/g, '').split(",")[0] < 26) {
                            $(this).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <!--Dropdown-->
    <label>
        Class currently studying in
        <em>*</em>
    </label>
    <select id="csin" name="Dropdown4">
        <option selected="true" value="-Select-">-Select-</option>
        <option id="cthoc" value="Class V">Class V</option>
        <option id="cthoc" value="Class VI">Class VI</option>
        <option id="cthoc" value="Class VII">Class VII</option>
        <option id="cthoc" value="Class VIII">Class VIII</option>
        <option id="cthoc" value="Class IX">Class IX</option>
        <option value="Class&#x20;X">Class X</option>
    </select>

    </div>
    </section>



    <section class="ep ep4 epm">
        <div class="column">
            <label>
                Mode of Exam
                <em>*</em>
            </label>
            <select id="QuestionOptions" name="Dropdown1">
                <option select value="Online">Online</option>
                <option id="option_2" value="Offline">Offline</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div id="A" class="column">
            <label>
                Online Exam Dates
                <em>*</em>
            </label>
            <select id="od" name="Dropdown2">
                <option selected="true" value="-Select-">-Select-</option>
                <option id="ctho" value="Dec&#x20;18,&#x20;2021">Dec 18, 2021</option>
                <option id="ctho" value="Dec&#x20;19,&#x20;2021">Dec 19, 2021</option>
                <option id="ctho" value="Dec&#x20;20,&#x20;2021">Dec 20, 2021</option>
                <option id="ctho" value="Dec&#x20;21,&#x20;2021">Dec 21, 2021</option>
                <option id="ctho" value="Dec&#x20;22,&#x20;2021">Dec 22, 2021</option>
                <option id="ctho" value="Dec&#x20;23,&#x20;2021">Dec 23, 2021</option>
                <option id="ctho" value="Dec&#x20;24,&#x20;2021">Dec 24, 2021</option>
                <option id="ctho" value="Dec&#x20;25,&#x20;2021">Dec 25, 2021</option>
                <option id="ctho2" value="Dec&#x20;26,&#x20;2021">Dec 26, 2021</option>
                <option id="ctho2" value="Dec&#x20;27,&#x20;2021">Dec 27, 2021</option>
                <option id="ctho2" value="Dec&#x20;28,&#x20;2021">Dec 28, 2021</option>
                <option id="ctho2" value="Dec&#x20;29,&#x20;2021">Dec 29, 2021</option>
                <option id="ctho2" value="Dec&#x20;30,&#x20;2021">Dec 30, 2021</option>
                <option id="ctho2" value="Dec&#x20;31,&#x20;2021">Dec 31, 2021</option>
            </select>
        </div>



        <div id="B" class="column">
            <label>
                Offline Exam Dates
                <em>*</em>
            </label>
            <select name="Dropdown3">
                <option selected="true" value="-Select-">-Select-</option>
                <option value="Dec&#x20;18,&#x20;2021">Dec 18, 2021</option>

            </select>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```